# looping over an array of mongodb document ids and querying that id and storing the result in a new array gives empty array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, nosql

Below is the code I am having issues with:

```
    const users = []
    event.registeredUsers.forEach(userId => {
            User.findOne({ _id: userId }).then(user => {
                console.log(user) // logs a valid user
                users.push(user)
            });
        });

    console.log(users) // logs empty array
```

The event is a MongoDB document that has registeredUsers field which is an array of MongoDB object Ids. When console logging the user returned in the then block it does shows a valid user document but when res.send(users) after the loop has been finished, it shows empty array in the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to execute promise based code inside forEach which doesnt work the way you expect it work. Use either `for..of` or `Promise.all`

`for..of` (sequential)

```
const users = []
for(const userId of event.registeredUsers) {
    User.findOne({ _id: userId }).then(user => {
       console.log(user) // logs a valid user
       users.push(user)
     });
 }

console.log(users)
```

`Promise.all` (in parallel)

```
Promise.all(event.registeredUsers.map(userId => {
    return User.findOne({ _id: userId }).then(user => {
       console.log(user) // logs a valid user
       return user;
     });
 }).then(users => console.log(users));
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an event loop issue.   Since User.findOne is a **Promise**, the `.then()` function will execute AFTER `console.log(users)`.

Here's a good video on JavaScript event loops:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ

Answer (score 0):

```
const followingId = ['63d76d37b5656f8db054f989','63d8cb0e1c7b21e93a714012']
const following = await User.find({ _id: { $in: followingId } }).select(' _id first_name last_name image block_user follow_user');
```

`followingId` is an array of Object Id and in the select method you can pass the fields that you want